# Matrikon OPC simulation Server doesnt have tags

Tags: postgresql, opc, historian

When launching the Matrikon Simulation Server when I connect to view the tags it doesnt contain any tags, I'm trying to generate random data to make a process historian. Do I need to download another software in order to see the tags with the data?

[image: OPC Explorer connected to Server]

[image: No tags available]